# Braille API using spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, braille

We are working on a project for Blind people.I want to call a BrailleApI from spring controller which will convert the alphabet characters to Braille equivalent
characters and display on webpage.
Has nay body worked on this? any sample code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one API that I have tested recently and seem to fit what you are looking for. http://funtranslations.com/api/braille . This offers braille conversion and has outputs for many different display types.